# Using UpdateResource() to update one's own resources

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources

I have an application whose resources need to be updated externally from time to time. I want the application to update it's own resources.

The problem with [UpdateResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is that it cannot be used on a currently executing process. Any ideas how I can update resources from the application itself instead of writing an external app to handle this?

regards,
andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be not a good solution to update the application resources. Programs are installed with Administrator rights. A standard user has no write access to the program executable files. Consider saving the data you need in a user directory. E.g. %LOCALAPPDATA%. If you really need resources you can also put a resource-only DLL there. Then it is easy to update even in a multi-user scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the resources to an external DLL and unload it while updating and reload
it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify your own executable.

Also, you must not do this. What if you're running from read-only drive?

For storing program state, there is %APPDATA%, %LOCALAPPDATA% and registry.

Comment: @Eugene...I realized that can't modify my own executable from this experience...however I do not wish to write another app to do the task, hence the question. Will try to implement the dll idea given by others...ThanQ